# Undecidability for hyperbolic Wang-tilings - pentagons, heptagons, octagons, oh my!

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling, decidability

Berger proved that the problem of determining if a finite set of [Wang tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) can tile the plane is undecidable.  [Robinson](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01418780) reproved Berger's result and raised the question of considering the decidability of the analogous tiling problem in the hyperbolic plane.  This problem was apparently show to also be undecidable independently by [Kari](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74593-8_6) and [Margenstern](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.4161).

My question is about what this problem of deciding the tileability of the hyperbolic plane actually is.  In Kari's article, he shows that the problem of tiling the hyperbolic plane with regular pentagons together with colored edges is undecidable, whereas in Margenstern's article he show the analogous result for a certain tiling by heptagons.

My motivation is I wanted to understand this result for the usual octagonal tiling of the hyperbolic plane associated with a genus 2 surface.  It turns out that the tiling problem here is also known to be undecidable by work of [Auburn, Barbieri, and Moutot](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08420) and I guess I am just looking for clarification that this does not also follow from the results of Kari/Margenstern.

My confusion is partially stemming from the fact that Kari says he "demonstrates the undecidability of the tiling problem  on the hyperbolic plane" and Margenstern says he proves that "the general tiling problem of the hyperbolic plane is undecidable" whereas from what I can tell they are each just tackling one kind of tiling of the hyperbolic plane and for any different tiling you need a different technique - is this true?

Sorry if that is all pretty muddled, I'm feeling pretty muddled about it all and would appreciate any pointers.